# ImageButton update source in AppWidget

Tags: android, android-widget, imagebutton

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of a ToggleButton in terms of RemoteViews, so I can have on in my App Widget. I have an ImageButton, and I've got it detecting clicks, but I'm having trouble changing the image that it displays when clicked. I'm under the impression I need to force the widget to update after it's been clicked to show the changes. Any idea what's the best way to go about it?

```
public class WifiWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

boolean toggleState = false;
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "com.nickavv.cleanwidgets.WIFICLICK";
Context myContext;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetIds[]) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    myContext = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("com.nickavv.cleanwidgets", R.layout.wifi_toggle_layout);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wifiToggleButton, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) { 
        switchToggle();
    }    
}

void switchToggle() {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("com.nickavv.cleanwidgets", R.layout.wifi_toggle_layout);
    Log.d("toggleState",""+toggleState);
    if(toggleState == false) {
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.wifiToggleButton, R.drawable.wifi_toggle_on);
    } else {
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.wifiToggleButton, R.drawable.wifi_toggle_off);          
    }
    toggleState = !toggleState;
    Log.d("toggleState",""+toggleState);
}
```

EDIT: Added this to the bottom of switchToggle:

```
AppWidgetManager myAWM = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(myContext);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(myContext, WifiWidget.class);
onUpdate(myContext, myAWM, myAWM.getAppWidgetIds(cn));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to update the widget. From the looks of this you can just call `onUpdate()` directly and read the button state in there to update your `RemoteViews` accordingly. Just use `RemoteViews.setImageViewResource()` to set the image that corresponds to the current button state.

All you need to call `onUpdate()` is the arguments, which you can get via a `Context`:

- Context: You can pass this from the receiver to `switchToggle()` and on to `onUpdate()`
- AppWidgetManager instance: get that via [`AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getInstance%28android.content.Context%29)
- App widget ids array: use [`AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getAppWidgetIds%28android.content.ComponentName%29)

`getAppWidgetIds()` takes a `ComponentName` as an argument. 
You can create one like below:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, WifiWidget.class);
```

You can also use this whole construct to update your app widgets from any given point, you are not bound to `onUpdate()`. Just use an addtional `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` call after you constructed your `RemoteViews` to publish them (which shows your UI changes).

Comment: So I added this to the bottom of the switchToggle function (I'll throw the actual code up in the question area), but when I click on the widget I get a Force Close, caused by a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace, the updated code and in which line the NPE occurs? =)

Comment: Your context must be null. Are you passing it as an argument to switchToggle() from the receiver?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't, and that stopped the force closes. Thanks! Now it just doesn't do anything. Also, I have those Log calls in switchToggle(), to tell me the state of the boolean variable at the beginning and end of the function, and each time it reports out "false, true", even though it should be alternating between that and "true, false"

Comment: Did you also change your `onUpdate()` to reflect the image change in the widget layout? Basically edit the RemoteViews like `if(toggleState == true) views.setImageViewResource(R.drawable.first) else views.setImageViewResources(R.drawable.sec);` where you also set the onClickListener.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3871/discussion-between-nick-and-alextsc)

Comment: I've tried to change image according the code Nick had provided, but the image isn't changing clicking on that. Would you please help me regarding this?